Summing up the binary entropy function
Reading the paper by Chase&Lovett: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.11689
I got stuck at the part calculating the sum of binary entropy functions.
Here is the part:

Let $A$, $B$ be two independent random variables taking values in $\{0,1\}^n$. 
Let $h(x)=-(x \log_2 x + (1-x) \log_2 (1-x))$ be the binary entropy function.  Then
$$ \frac{1}{2\psi^*} \left( \mathbb{E}_{A_{<i}} [p(A_{<i})] \cdot \mathbb{E}_{B_{<i}} [h(q(B_{<i}))] + \mathbb{E}_{B_{<i}} [q(B_{<i})] \cdot \mathbb{E}_{A_{<i}} [h(p(A_{<i}))] \right)\\=\frac{1}{2\psi^*} \left( \mathbb{P}[A_i=0] \cdot H(B \vert B_{<i}) + \mathbb{P}[B_i=0] \cdot H(A \vert A_{<i}) \right) $$

I am confused with the reason why
$$ \mathbb{E}_{A_{<i}} [p(A_{<i})] = \mathbb{P}[A_i=0] $$
and
$$ \mathbb{E}_{B_{<i}} [h(q(B_{<i}))] = H(B \vert B_{<i})$$
Since I am a beginner in the probability theory, could you please explain it with any probabilistic intuitions or the properties of entropy?
Thank you.

Your post should be maximally self-contained, with all definitions present. Anyhow, this question does not seem to be for this forum. You may want to try https://math.stackexchange.com/
